# android customization manager

Tags: android, customization

I would like to customize my android app looks. The idea is following:

```
In web service I choose user and for that user I choose :
 - button background color
 - background color
 - font color 
 - what modules are available (tabs on/off in tabHost)

 etc ..
```

In my android app user start to login and then download settings set in web services.

```
 (ButtonColor : red, BacgroundColor : black, Module1 : true..... etc.)
```

Now I want to apply that color to all my app activities.

Any idea how to achive that ?

I do little research and I could do what I want by XML style file, but I can't change XML attributes ( example button color) at runtime. I can change however theme at runtime, but in xml theme i still need to change hardcoded attributes at runtime to set color.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that when you show the activity you can loop through all your controls and set the colors at that time.